# .htaccess - redirect anchor link

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want:
http://www.example.com/#test to be redirected to http://www.example.com/test

With .htaccess, is that possible? How?

Comment: It is possible!
Use the [NE] flag.
See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2285193/htaccess-redirect-to-page-with-anchor-link

Comment: It is possible!
Use the [NE] flag: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2285193/htaccess-redirect-to-page-with-anchor-link

Comment: @linuxmarc, that's only for the destination url, but you apparently can't match against an anchor in a RewriteRule because the anchor part is not sent to the server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anchors are not sent to the server as part of a request, so no, you cannot redirect based on them.

http://www.mikeduncan.com/named-anchors-are-not-sent/