# .htaccess redirect to page with anchor link

Tags: mod-rewrite

I'm trying to set up a .htaccess file to redirect pages from one domain to another. Works in 99% of cases, the RewriteRules that aren't working are like the one below - if the outbound URL has an #anchor tag, the # symbol is converted into the characters %23 in the browser and then the page does not load at the anchor. Any idea on how to interpret the # tag correctly?

```
AddType x-mapp-php5 .php
AddHandler x-mapp-php5 .php
Options -MultiViews
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule bg/row_b1_i_pn1.php http://example.org/s-b-g/b-1#illustration-110
```

If I cut and paste "http://example.org/s-b-g/b-1#illustration-110" into my browser directly, it loads just fine, but using the RewriteRule, the URL that loads is "http://example.org/s-b-g/b-1%23illustration-110" ... The new site is a drupal site, if that helps any. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it with the [*NE* flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/rewrite_flags.html#flag_ne):

```
RewriteRule bg/row_b1_i_pn1.php http://example.org/s-b-g/b-1#illustration-110 [NE]
```

Answer (score 0):

because .htaccess usually interprets # as a comment it kind of defeats proper interpretation ..
so instead of using the # in your rewrite rule actually use the %23 code instead.
so your rewrite becomes:
RewriteRule bg/row_b1_i_pn1.php http://example.org/s-b-g/b-1%23illustration-110 [NE]

more accurately is becomes:
RewriteRule bg/row_b1_i_pn1.php http://example.org/s-b-g/b-1/%23illustration-110 [NE]